# i want written equation with key in one line

Tags: equations

i want written this

[image]

but lack a braces, 
How can I write just like the image?

```
    \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{copyrightbox}
    \begin{document}





\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
   p_1=    \begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\
   1&\\
   -1
   \end{bmatrix},t_1=\begin{bmatrix}
   0
   \end{bmatrix}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
   p_1=    \begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\
   1&\\
   -1
   \end{bmatrix},t_1=\begin{bmatrix}
   0
   \end{bmatrix}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

this is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses basic `array`s and extensible delimiters to achieve the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{
    \vec{p}_1 = \left[\begin{array}{@{} r @{}}
      -1 \\ 1 \\ -1
   \end{array}\right],
    t_1 = [1]
  \right\} \quad
  \left\{
    \vec{p}_2 = \left[\begin{array}{@{} r @{}}
      1 \\ 1 \\ -1
   \end{array}\right],
    t_2 = [0]
  \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

`@{}` in a column specification removes the spacing usually inserted at that point. So, `\begin{array}{@{} r @{}}` denotes an `array` without column spaces on the left and right of a single `r`ight-aligned column.